# Transferring from a Samsung Galaxy to a Mac

Tags: photos, macos

Is it ok to connect a Samsung Galaxy to a Mac for transferring photos?
I'm not sure if it is ok to do this with two different brands.

Answer (score 3):

A good wireless method that I use between Android and Mac is Soduto with KdeConnect.

Both are open source apps.

You can find Soduto for Mac here https://soduto.com/

You can find KDEConnect for Android here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en_IN&gl=US

Now install these and make sure they are on the same Wifi network. Then Pair the two devices (using Soduto on mac to pair with Android through KDEConnect).

Pairing is necessary only once, and you can transfer files and even your Clipboard history across the two devices anytime you want without the hassle of connecting wires!!

Answer (score 1):

Zero problem. Just use the USB cable and transfer the files, or go by bluetooth if you have the time. Both work flawless. Airdrop also works if you want to use an app and transfer over wlan. If you use the USB cable, you will get a lot of mac files on your Galaxy's SD card file system, like a file called ".DS_Store" in each folder. This doesn't hurt, but you might want to remove them or wonder where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine. You can use whatever software you want to do the transfer.

Comment: Fantastic, will get straight on it. Appreciate the prompt advice!

Answer (score 0):

I also have a galaxy and a mac, and it doesn't work for me. I'd recommend this mimic of airdrop, called Airdroid. Very straightforward. You go to  http://web.airdroid.com/ then install the app on your galaxy, scan a QR code displayed on the website then transfer whatever. Logins optional, whole process takes 2-3 minutes each time.